# Help Picking a Statistical Test Please

Tags: r, categorical-data, continuous-data

My experiment is looking into visual long-term memory - specifically, does the level of categorical interference affect memory?

One sub-section of the analyses involves looking at whether participant's reaction time (to press the left/right arrow key) was significantly influenced by the level of categorical interference.

This is a summary table I made in R:

```
 Interference Level:             Avg Reaction Time(ms):                                                 
  4                              1123.696                                                 
  20                             1225.238                                               
  40                             1283.473                                                 
  60                             1265.762
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with what statistical test to use?

**EDIT**:

My DV (reaction time) is continuously measured (milliseconds).

But my IV (interference level) is ordinal, with 4 levels (4,20,40,60).

Each participant is measured at every interference level, 3 times each.

i.e. each participant sees and is tested on 3 categories that have 4 interference, 3 categories that have 20 interference, 3 with 40 and 3 with 60. There are 12 categories in total.

Each participant sees all 12 categories, but which category has what type of interference is randomised and counterbalanced across our sample of 24 participants.

Thank you in advance for any help/advice!

Comment: Are you sure *Interference level* is categorical, and not ordinal?

Comment: And is each participant measured for each *Interference level*?

Comment: Ah yes sorry you are correct, interference level is ordinal. And yes each participant is measured for each interference level (3 times over) - see my edit in original post above.

Comment: It sounds like you have a relatively complex design with effects nested within one another and the same subject being measured multiple times.  I suspect you will want to use a multi-level (mixed effects) model.  Understanding how to correctly specify this type of model is not trivially easy.

Comment: Kruskal-Wallis is a common nonparametric test, but it won't capture the complexity of your experimental design.  If you need to simply things down to the two variables presented in your table, you might use linear regression or Kendall correlation to find the relationship between the two.  But this isn't the best approach for your design.